# Django Send Email inputting whitespace character into link?

Tags: django

Im building an html email from scratch and then sending it through the email.send() function of EMailMEssage. My Html takes in links from an assets path in on the site and sends it through the email for users to download. Now for some reason when i display the email in an email client my url looks as follows. "myWebSite/media/**th%20umbnails**/2013/09/10/v4_t.png" as you can see the client is rendering the link with a whitespace between th and um of the word thumbnails and I cant figure out as to why. ANy other questions please ask. Im really stumped by this...

Comment: maybe some more details.. template + view would be nice.

Comment: Well I dont have a template. Theres only a view and a model. I have a few functions that create an html string by pulling data from the model. The html string is sent to the send mail class of Django which sends out the email to the user who input their email. Right now I am at home and the code is at my job but tomororw ill update this post with the code.